# Executing same Kernel multiple times in OpenCL

Tags: kernel, opencl

I want to run a kernel(same) multiple times( lets say 3 times) in parallel with OpenCL. I read similar title threads but i am still confused. I have already wrote a program that executes it once.I know i need to make changes to clEnqueueNDKernelRangeKernel( ) and i tried but failed. So kindly can someone tell me how can i do it multiple times. Thanks for help.

```
//Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define DATA_SIZE 10

using namespace std;

const char *ProgramSource =
"__kernel void add(__global float *inputA, __global float *inputB, __global 
float *inputC, __global float *output)\n"\
"{\n"\
"  size_t id = get_global_id(0);\n"\
"float f;\n"\
"float y1 = 0.0f;\n"\
"y1 = inputA[id] + inputB[id] + inputC[id];\n"\
"  output[id] = y1;\n"\
"}\n";

int main(void)
{
cl_context context;
cl_context_properties properties[3];
cl_kernel kernel;
cl_command_queue command_queue;
cl_program program;
cl_int err;
cl_uint num_of_platforms = 0;
cl_platform_id platform_id;
cl_device_id device_id;
cl_uint num_of_devices = 0;
cl_mem inputA, inputB, inputC, output;

size_t global;

float inputDataA[DATA_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
float inputDataB[DATA_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
float inputDataC[DATA_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };    
float y1[DATA_SIZE] = { 0 };
int i;

// retreive a list of platforms avaible
if (clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &num_of_platforms) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Unable to get platform_id\n");
    return 1;
}

// try to get a supported GPU device
if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, 
&num_of_devices) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Unable to get device_id\n");
    return 1;
}

// context properties list - must be terminated with 0
properties[0] = CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
properties[1] = (cl_context_properties)platform_id;
properties[2] = 0;

// create a context with the GPU device
context = clCreateContext(properties, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);

// create command queue using the context and device
command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

// create a program from the kernel source code
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char 
**)&ProgramSource, NULL, &err);

// compile the program
if (clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error building program\n");
    return 1;
}

// specify which kernel from the program to execute
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "add", &err);

// create buffers for the input and ouput
inputA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
inputB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
inputC = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);

// load data into the input buffer
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputA, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, inputDataA, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputB, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, inputDataB, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputC, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, inputDataC, 0, NULL, NULL);
// set the argument list for the kernel command
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputA);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputB);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputC);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);

global = DATA_SIZE;

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clFinish(command_queue);

// copy the results from out of the output buffer
clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) *DATA_SIZE, y1, 0, NULL, NULL);

// print the results
printf("y1: ");

for (i = 0; i<DATA_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%f\n ", y1[i]);
}

// cleanup - release OpenCL resources
clReleaseMemObject(inputA);
clReleaseMemObject(inputB);
clReleaseMemObject(inputC);
clReleaseMemObject(output);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
clReleaseContext(context);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: "i tried but failed" - what did you try, how did it fail?

Comment: I changed SetkernelArg() parameter but it was not working but now i get correct results if i  write clEnqueueNDKernelRangeKernel( ) command 3 time. But i am not sure if these 3 commands are running in parallel independently.

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] to your question: if we cannot replicate your results, it gets that much harder for us to offer advice on what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are working with a command queue and a given device context.

Two things:

- If you have not specified something particularly, the commands will be executed in order and never in parallel independently on the queue.

  - Create multiple queues for each kernel execution in order to execute the kernel  in parallel independently on each queue (3 queues for 3 executions).
  - This approach is wasteful for many independent parallel executions. Thus, i do not see much of a benefit in this. However: OpenCl is all about performance measuring in order to see the benefit of the approach and I do not know yours.
- Better write a function that does the steps (buffer creation, buffer filling, argument setting, kernel execution request, reading from buffer, buffer deletion) and call it multiple times. In order to maximize performance, do only create the buffers once and delete them as your program ends. Reuse them as often as possible (if you do it sequentially).

Last but not least: Measure the performance increase and evaluate which approach fits best for your problem.

Comment: i have added a simple example of array addition, can you tell me where i need to make changes to run this kernel 3 times in parallel independently. It will help ma a lot .Thanks